# Python: Use subprocess to run CMD, used to flash an stm32 uC

Tags: python, subprocess

I have some trouble to flash an stm32 over a python script. I'm using the ST-LINK_CLI.exe, provided by the ST Link Utility tool, to flash the uC and it works by using the CMD in Windows, but not over the python tool.

The error I get back from the subprocess.run(...) is "Unable to open file!" for the path I provide, but the same path works fine in the CMD from Windows.

```
import subprocess
path = 'C:/Users/U1/Desktop/test.hex'
path = path.encode('utf-8')

stlink_output=[]

try:
  stlink_output = subprocess.run(
    ["ST-LINK_CLI.exe", "-c", "ID=0", "SWD", "-P", str(path), "-V", "-HardRST", "-Rst"],
    check=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode().splitlines()
except:
  print("An error occured")

print(stlink_output)
```

Has anyone an idea, what can be wrong with the provided path? Should I use a different encoding?

Comment: Please try to build the path using `os.path.join()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not decoding your path, just casting your bytes as string, so you get a path like

`"b'C:/Users/U1/Desktop/test.hex'"`

Try to decode instead to get proper string

`stlink_output = subprocess.run(
    ["ST-LINK_CLI.exe", "-c", "ID=0", "SWD", "-P", path.decode(), "-V", "-HardRST", "-Rst"],
    check=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode().splitlines()`

Comment: Thx, the path seems to be known now, but I get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb1 in position 511: invalid start byte

Comment: Maybe you could just use no encoding at all ? Not sure where it comes from since I can't reproduce it, which version of python are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.8, no encoding seems also not to work

Answer (score 0):

If You're sure the output values are *text* please consider using `run` `text=True` parameter (and `encoding` if needed).

Just define path as string and use it (no need to encode/decode).

Also for python 3.4+ it is recommended to use `pathlib` module (allows neat checks and user expansion in Your code later).
So the code would look something like:

```
import subprocess
import pathlib
# `~` gets converted to current user home with expanduser()
# i.e. `C:/Users/U1` in Your case
path = pathlib.Path('~/Desktop/test.hex').expanduser()

if not path.exists():
    raise FileNotFoundError(path)

stlink_output = subprocess.run(
    ["ST-LINK_CLI.exe", "-c", "ID=0", "SWD", "-P", path, "-V", "-HardRST", "-Rst"],
    check=False,
    # text option without decoding requires py3.7+...
    # text=True,
    # stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.splitlines()
    # ...so this is variant pre python3.7:
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode().splitlines()

print(stlink_output)
```

Comment: Thx, but I get an error from the interpreter: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Comment: My mistake: that text option is available only in python 3.7+
Fixed.